# 'post' object is not iterable in django and it is showing error but i'm not getting what's going wrong on code

Tags: python, django

> TypeError at /dashboard
> 'post' object is not iterable i am just try to get data from db table and show on dashboard in dabel form

> my `dashboard.html` page

```
     {% if posts %}
<table class="table table-dark table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="width:3%">ID</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:30%">Title</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:55%">Description</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:15%">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
    {% for post in posts %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{posts.id}} </td>
      <td>{{posts.title}}</td>
      <td>{{posts.desc}}</td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Edit</a>
      <form action ='' , method ='POST' class='d-inline'>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' value ='Delete' >
      </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{% else %}
<h4 class =' text-center alert alert-warning'>No Records  </h4>
{% endif %}
</div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

> my views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        posts= post.objects.all()
        return render(request,'dashboard.html',{'posts':post})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('login')
```

> urls.py

```
path('dashboard',views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `views.py` file. Try change this:

`return render(request,'dashboard.html',{'posts':post})`
to this:

`return render(request,'dashboard.html',{'posts':posts})`

Comment: Make sure your database table has some data to show in **dashboard table**

Answer (score 0):

I assume in template dashboard.html you have to change this :

```
{% for post in posts %}
<tr>
<td>{{posts.id}} </td>
<td>{{posts.title}}</td>
<td>{{posts.desc}}</td>
```

to this :

```
{% for post in posts %}
<tr>
<td>{{post.id}} </td>
<td>{{post.title}}</td>
<td>{{post.desc}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```html
{% for post in posts %}
<tr>
<td>{{post.id}} </td>
<td>{{post.title}}</td>
<td>{{post.desc}}</td>
```